# Can Tor really hide my location when I access websites that has the tracing function?

Tags: onion-services

I'm totally new to Tor.

I'm kind of stalking some people's blogs and I don't want to let them know. For example if I access someone's wordpress blog (which can trace your locations) using Tor, is it gonna hide my location and what's the blogger gonna see in the stats section? How is it going to appear to them?

Do I need to change anything in Tor's settings in order to hide my location?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would suggest reading: [What is Tor?](https://2019.www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en)

When you use Tor, the website will only see the Tor exit node. It will never see you. This means that you remain anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Tor is a network of virtual tunnels that allows you to improve your privacy and security on the Internet. Tor works by sending your traffic through three random servers (also known as relays) in the Tor network. The last relay in the circuit (the “exit relay”) then sends the traffic out onto the public Internet. So, the website can only see the exit relay. You can refer here for more information on this: https://tb-manual.torproject.org/about/

> Do I need to change anything in Tor's settings in order to hide my location?

It is highly recommended to **NOT** tweak any of the default settings in order to prevent fingerprinting. Although you might change the [security settings](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/security-settings/) as per your use case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer give by Championquizzer is really complete but I'd like to add something, apart from now tweaking the default settings if you don't know what you are doing, you should enable the "Safest" mode in settings, this will block any javascript which I really recommend, but keep in mind some pages may not work without it.